# Matching two models up with directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to solve an issue with the design of my models, view, and directive in AngularJS. Essentially I have a list of products being populated on the page by category with quantity fields being added for each one. I need these quantity fields to have bidirectional binding with an array of orderItem that I return from and post to the server.

Currently I can get the oc.order.orderItems array to update with new orderItem when I change the quantity field of a product. But when I try to populate a previous order, I am having trouble updating the model and view. Majority of my issue stems from how I should handle the ngModel attribute of the quantity field tied with my directive.

Here are some of my code samples (slightly stripped down). If anything needs clarification to help with the assist, because I know this sounds confusing, please let me know.

Product Model:

```
var product = { id: 1, category_id: 1, name: 'Apple' };
```

OrderItem Model:

```
var orderItem = { id: 1, order_id: 1, product_id: 1, quantity: 2 };
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in oc.categories">
    <h2>{{ category.name }}<h2>
    <div ng-repeat="product in category.products">
        <h3>{{ product.name }}</h3>

        <input type="number" placeholder="Quantity" 
               order-item="product" ng-model="oc.order.orderItems[$index]" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular
    .module('OrderApp')
    .directive('orderItem', function ($window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope : {
                product: '=orderItem'
            },
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

                ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                    if (!viewValue > 0) return;

                    if (!scope.id) scope.id = 0;
                    if (!scope.order_id) scope.order_id = 0;

                    return {
                        id: scope.id,
                        order_id: scope.order_id,
                        quantity: viewValue,
                        product_id: scope.product.id
                    };
                });

                ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                    if (!modelValue) return;

                    if (!modelValue.id) scope.id = modelValue.id;
                    if (!modelValue.order_id) scope.order_id = modelValue.order_id;

                    return modelValue.quantity;
                });

            }
        };
    });
```

(Directive doesn't seem right at all and don't know where to put a view $render and scope $watch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the problem differently, I found that my solution should not have been a directive but actually a service to share the data for each model between controllers.

Solution: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/pmigliaccio/a32bd80cfe3faec9e5c67e26ff45dc7a)